# Rigidly joining two angles separated by 1"

Tags: metal, construction

I need to attach a 3/4" wide, 1/8" thick steel angle to a perpindicular 1" wide, 1/8" thick steel angle as depicted. The angles should be rigidly joined so that a force of about 100 lbs. in any direction on either angle would not cause it to move. The challenge is that the angles are offset by 1". I would prefer not to use glue because I would like to be able to disassemble and reassemble the device.

[image: device]

There is not enough room for multiple screws holding the angles together and even if there were, the angles would be able to rotate as the screws would not sufficiently prevent torsion about the midpoint of the screws.

A pipe could be placed around a long screw, holding the angles 1" apart, but the angles would be able to rotate and possibly shear against the pipe.

A 1" cube bracket could be screwed to the 3/4" angle on both of its faces and could be screwed to the 1" bracket twice on one face. The cube could be cut from a square steel tube. I am not sure this arrangement would provide the necessary rigidity but it's better than the options above.

How can these angles be attached?

Comment: Not move? That stuff will flex...

Comment: @SolarMike  Will depend on the length.  Short lengths should hold 100 pounds.  3 or 4 feet will be different.

Comment: +1 for the 3D drawing

Comment: @crip659 you're talking probably inches.  Any more, and the angle will flex in one direction or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut to size a **U** shaped 1 inch profile.

Now you can attach it with 6 nuts and bolts to hold in place and connect the two **L** profiles

[image: u profile]

Comment: This is similar to the 1" cube bracket idea. I think I could fit 3 screws in the 1" angle and 2 screws on each side of the 3/4" angle. I'm convinced there would be enough shear strength with that setup.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica correct, but with cube it is more difficult to place the screws, you will have to drill all the way

Comment: @ReinstateMonica  I would use bolts instead of screws.  You do need to worry about threads stripping, if you need to take it apart often.

Comment: @crip659 I meant machine screws with nuts and washers. What's the difference between those and bolts?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica  Machine screws good, plain metal screws(no nuts) not so good.   I am not sure if machine screws have a grading system(probably do), do know bolts have a grading system for strength.  Found that out on a small square hay baler.  Grade two bolts would shear every few bales, a grade five would last all day and more.

Answer (score 2):

Two 1/4 or 5/16 inch bolts at an angle should hold and be small enough to fit.

A sleeve over the bolts between the angle irons will keep them apart and provide rigidity.

Comment: Wouldn't torsion be an issue though? When providing torque on the angles, the screws would try to rotate; being at angles, there would be a lot of leverage forcing the screws to straighten or further bend. I predict the screw heads would fail or the angles would wobble.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica  Grade five or better grade 8 bolts will take quite a bit of force to break/bend.  Even grade two bolts with only a foot or two length of the angles should hold 100 pounds.  It will depend on how far the 100 pounds is from the mounting point of the two angles.

Answer (score 2):

A machined cube that has reliefs with shoulders cut for both angles will give better location than just bolts will do.

Then the two angels can have separate tapped bolts and holes.